# altering gsap timeline position parameter dynamically

Tags: javascript, gsap

I have several gsap timelines that start at different times.

in my setting it is nescessary to use the position parameter for the timelines for sequencing. `delay()` is unfortunately not possible.

here is some sample code:

```js
sampleTimeline= new TimelineMax({paused: true,onComplete:restartSampleTimeline},0)
.to("#sampleblock",2,{x:"200px"},2) /* <-- this parameter needs to be dynamic */
.to("#sampleblock",2,{x:"0px"},4);

var count = 0;

function restartSampleTimeline(){
  $("#sampleblock").html(count);
  count++;
  if(count>=1){
     // at this position, i want to skip the two seconds / change the number "2"! 
     sampleTimeline.restart();
    }else{ 
     sampleTimeline.restart();
  }
}

sampleTimeline.play();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/TimelineMax.min.js"></script>
<div id="sampleblock">haha</div>
```

what i want to achieve is to (as you can see in my comment in the javascript section) alter the position parameter of the first `to()` after a specific condition (in this case `var count >=1`)

is there any way to do this? i was not able to "just use a variable as position parameter", because it only remembers the first state of the given variable...

thanks in advance :)

Comment: which version of greensock are you using? Their example for 1.19.0 shows the parameter value can be calculated on the fly, no? https://greensock.com/1-19-0/

Comment: yea, i'm using 1.19.0.. the thing is, as far as i know/my experience is, that "calculated on the fly" means, that you can use a variable for the parameter, but after the timeline is set, it takes the initial value of the variable and does not refresh it... am i wrong??

Comment: ... could you make a codepen from your snippets? is your intent to keep the animation looping the way it does? i'd be curious to play with it for a bit, mainly to see what a function as a parameter would do.

Comment: here i tried to use a function, but i had no success: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KNRdyZ?editors=1011 as you can see, the console.log() only gets executed once

Comment: yeah, you're right, but... when you restart you can pass altered params to it: 
sampleTimeline.restart( ).to("#sampleblock",2,{x:"200px"},returnDelay());

... perhaps that's one way to approach it

Answer (score -2, accepted):

okay, so i came to a conclusion!

i found out, that there are two possible ways to achieve, what i wanted. 
for me, only the first one works... the second one is not possible in my setting...

**######## 1st Solution ########**

in my case, i wanted to skip thw first tween delay... so what i did, was to change the second tween to `"+=0"` so that it always starts imediately after the tween before and let the first tween, how it was...

the thing i changed was `if(count>=1)` to restart the timeline and seek the wished position.... so my final result ist the following:

```js
sampleTimeline= new TimelineMax({paused: true,onComplete:restartSampleTimeline},0)
.to("#sampleblock",2,{x:"200px"},2)
.to("#sampleblock",2,{x:"0px"},"+=0");

var count = 0;

function restartSampleTimeline(){
  $("#sampleblock").html(count);
  count++;
  if(count>=1){
     sampleTimeline.restart();
     sampleTimeline.seek(2);
    }else{ 
     sampleTimeline.restart();
  }
}

sampleTimeline.play();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/TimelineMax.min.js"></script>
<div id="sampleblock">haha</div>
```

**######## 2nd Solution ########**

unfortunately, that solution did not work in my case but for future reference, there is a posibility, to change the value dynamically... you can use a function as parameter... but as i already said in the comments, that function gets only called one initial time... so what you can do, is to regenerate the timeline...

the following is a example, how to achieve that:

```js
sampleTimeline= new TimelineMax({paused: true,onComplete:restartSampleTimeline},0)
.to("#sampleblock",2,{x:"200px"},returnDelay("first"))
.to("#sampleblock",2,{x:"0px"},"+=0");

var count = 0;

function restartSampleTimeline(){
  $("#sampleblock").html(count);
  count++;
  if(count>=1){
     sampleTimeline.clear();
     sampleTimeline
     .to("#sampleblock",2,{x:"200px"},returnDelay("not-first"))
     .to("#sampleblock",2,{x:"0px"},"+=0");
    sampleTimeline.play();
    }else{ 
     sampleTimeline.restart();
  }
}

sampleTimeline.play();

function returnDelay(i){
  if(i=="first"){
    return 2;
  }
  if(i!="first"){
    return 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/TimelineMax.min.js"></script>
<div id="sampleblock">haha</div>
```

i hope, that helps some people with a similar problem in the future :)